# Understanding distribution of permutations defined by elements in finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

I'm studying the paper *Polynomial evaluation and message authentication* https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/pema-20071022.pdf , by Daniel J. Bernstein.  He frequently makes arguments like the following:

> Fix a finite field $k$.  [Generate] 9 independent uniform
> random secrets $r1, r2, . . . , r8, s \in k$.
>
> ...[T]he sender wants to send a message $m$... where $m$ is a sequence of 8 components $m1,m2, . . . ,m8 \in k$.
> The sender transmits $m$ together with the authenticator $a = m1r1 + · · · + m8r8 + s \in k$.
>
> ...From the attacker’s point of view, given (m, a), all #k8 choices of (r1, . . . , r8)
> are equally likely: **each choice of (r1, . . . , r8) is consistent with exactly one choice
> of s.** (emphasis added)

I am trying to understand his claim that each choice of $r_1...r_8$ is consistent with exactly one choice of $s$.  Outside of finite fields, I do not believe this to be true: That is, in general (not restricted to finite fields), many choices of $r_1...r_8$ may exclude certain $s$.

Below is what I've reasoned.  Is it correct?

In a group, each element defines a permutation.  The converse is not necessarily true: Other than the symmetric group, many permutations will not have a corresponding element which performs them.

Similarly, in a field, each non-zero element defines two permutations.

Consequently, if $a$ and $b$ are randomly selected from group $G$ or field $F$ with uniform probability, $ab$ has uniform probability over the entire $G$ or $F$.  This has clear implications for cryptography: We can select any non-zero element at random and use it without fear that operating it will enter a trap.  In this sense, all elements of the field are "equal" in that they each define a permutation.

## Exponentiation

In section 4.2, Bernstein uses similar arguments to replace $r_1...r_8$ with $r^1...r^8$:

> authenticator $a = m_1r^8 + · · · + m_8r + s \in k$.

This was very surprising! I can only partially justify it, as follows:

Since every finite field is cyclic, if $r$ is a generator for the field, if $n$ is a random variable with uniform probability, $r^n$ will be randomly distributed over the field with uniform probability.  This has the same advantages.

What if $r$ is not a generator? It would seem that $r^n$ will only map to certain elements of the field, making $r^n$ poorly suited for crypto.  Yet Bernstein makes no such restriction on $r$ being a generator.  Can you please help me understand this?

---

### Update

In discussing the Bernstein paper, Proctor writes ( https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/613.pdf ):

> . When encrypted with a one-time pad, the digest
> output from [Bernstein] forms an information-theoretic message authentication code.

This is a great way to consolidate my question: **Under what circumstances does finite field addition, multiplication, or exponentiation by a randomly selected element act like a one-time pad?**

My tentative answer is:

1. Addition: Always
2. Multiplication: Iff the element is non-zero
3. Exponentiation: Iff the base element is a generator

Comment: I don't know the setting, so I don't know which variables are known to which party. Presumably your boldfaced concern is explained by the fact that we can solve for $s$ in terms of the others:
$$s=a-m_1r_2-m_2r_2-\cdots-m_8r_8.$$
My guess is that the sender can use this dependence of $m, s$ and $a$ as evidence for them knowing the $r_i$s to any other party who knows $m$ and the $r_i$s, but that is not clear to me. In line with your answer 2 it seems prudent to insist that $r_i\neq0$ for all $i$ (or at least for most $i$).

Comment: The parts about exponentiation leave me even further in the dark. If $r$ is a uniform random variable taking values from a finite field $k$ with $q$ elements, then $r^m$ is another such random variable if and only if $\gcd(m,q-1)=1$. This probably suffices for Bernstein in his use of degree $8$ polynomials. However, the variables $r,r^2,\ldots,r^8$ most certainly are not independent given that the others are functions of $r$.  I understood the choice of $r$ to be random and the exponents to be fixed to this set.

Comment: True, if $r$ is a fixed primitive element (= a generator of $k^*$) then we can uniformly draw exponents $m$ from $[0,q-2]$ and get a uniformly distributes elements $r^m$ of $k^*$. I don't know if this is what you were aiming at.